# Illumos/Solaris equivalent of FreeBSD devd (daemon to run userland programs when kernel events happen)?

Tags: freebsd, solaris, illumos

I have been searching the [illumos man pages](https://illumos.org/man/) for an equivalent of FreeBSD's [`devd`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=devd&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) (way to run programs based upon kernel events), but I could not find any.

Is there an Illumos/Solaris equivalent of FreeBSD's `devd` daemon, providing a way to have userland programs run when certain kernel events happen?

Comment: You can use dTrace "destructive actions" to send signals or run `system()` commands.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E53395/gkwvl.html

Comment: Thanks for mentioning dTrace for sending signals. If I am not mistaken, dTrace was released in 2005. I wonder how they were sending signals based on kernel events before that time?